# Flask run on google colab: server side page loading problem

Tags: javascript, python, flask, deep-learning

I am trying to train an nlp model and then show the result using python and Flask, in a Google Colab Python notebook.
In the first step I use FinBert which is financial model based on Bert neural network. it gets a text.txt file that contain news texts and the output is the sentiment of each text. Here is the problem when I try to show the output on '0.0.0.0:5000' port it fails to work.
By the way I run my codes on 'google colab'.

```
here is the code: 
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
import sys
import optparse
import time
from flask import request
import sys
from finbert.finbert import predict
from pytorch_pretrained_bert.modeling import BertForSequenceClassification
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
start = int(round(time.time()))
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('./models/', num_labels=3, cache_dir=None)

@app.route("/",methods=['POST'])
def score():
    text=request.get_json()['text']
    return(predict(text, model).to_json(orient='records'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=False, threaded=True)
```

I want to check if the problem is from model or not so I delete the flask part and just pass some text to the model and it works fine. Therefore there is some problem with flask which I can't fined (completely new to flask).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not confident if this is going to be a prompt solution for your case but the last time I had an issue and could not find any more solution, just downgrading flask solved the issue, for which I spent a few days to find a solution/error

```
!pip install flask==0.12.2
```

If this is the solution, the credit should go to [this](https://github.com/gstaff/flask-ngrok/blob/master/examples/flask_ngrok_example.ipynb)